# ruby async monitoring

Tags: ruby, asynchronous

I want to monitor last modified files in browser in real time.

i.e. I am editing file in my editor, and when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, browser change displayed information, also file shared in local network, and I want to monitor changes from other people

What ruby libraries(or maybe not only ruby) I must to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use [Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard), which is just a wrapper around whatever the OS provides, such as inotify or kqueues.